# Как определить вводится дробное число или целое?

Tags: c++

Вводится размер одномерного массива, размер типа int и если вводится отрицательное число или дробное, нужно вывести ошибку. С отрицательным числом понятно как сделать, а как быть с вводом дробного числа?

Comment: Если совсем просто, то прочтите размер в переменную типа double и проверьте, целое ли в ней число. Если же серьезно, тогда не забудьте проверять, что ввод вообще успешен, т.е. может вы пытались ввести вовсе не число... Тогда см. ответ @Harry

Comment: А как проверить что число целое?

Comment: Самое простое -- присвоить переменной типа int и сравнить ее с double

Answer (score 0):

Раз у вас C++, наверное, вы вводите

```
int n;
cin >> n;
```

Тогда просто проверяйте состояние потока - при попытке ввода он будет в состоянии fail.

Вот, когда-то для студентов набрасывал :)

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите размер массива",1,10);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, и всё же нельзя это как то более просто реализовать?

Comment: Элементарно! Не прогуливать лекции и читать учебники.